# Need PL/SQL block to retrieve data as per my requirement

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I'm having a table ABC. In this table, on the basis of AGE, I need to find Duplicates and for those duplicate records, I need some selected colums in `dbms_output.put_line`.

```
DECLARE 
CURSOR C_AGE IS 
SELECT AGE FROM ABC
GROUP BY AGE
HAVING COUNT(1)>1 ;
BEGIN
FOR RECS IN C_AGE
LOOP
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (recs.age);
END LOOP;
end;
```

In above code, instead of displaying AGE, I need ID, Name, AGE columns in output.
    Pls suggest.

Below is alternative select statement for the same. But I don't wanna use sub-query. Bcoz in Prod I have one heavy table where I wanna apply same logic.
    So need to go with cursor.

```
select ID,Name,AGE from abc where age in (
SELECT age FROM ABC
GROUP BY AGE
HAVING COUNT(1)>1);
```

Answer (score 1):

> But I don't wanna use sub-query. Bcoz in Prod I have one heavy table
>   where I wanna apply same logic. So need to go with cursor.

Why do you presume that looping through the `CURSOR` to display in a PL/SQL block is efficient than a simple select statement?

I could give you this query as another alternative to your sub-query select, using `COUNT` analytic function.

```
SELECT ID
    ,Name
    ,AGE
FROM (
    SELECT a.*
        ,COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY AGE) AS c
    FROM abc a
    ) where c > 1;
```

If you still want to apply same logic in PL/SQL using a loop, do it only if you are performing any DMLs (`INSERT`,`UPDATE` etc, dynamic DDLs etc. Otherwise, pure sql select or single `open cursor` with select would suffice for displaying output or passing a `CURSOR` to external application resp.